# Editing the column span in CSS, code is ignored

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have added the following lines to my style.css sheet after inspecting the elements on Google Chrome so that my instagram icon could fit on my website [mamou-mani.com](http://mamou-mani.com):

```
#footer > div.column.span-7.1 append-0.5 #footer > div.column.span-8.append-0\2e 5 #footer > div.column.span-20.append-1
```

However it is ignored when I save style.css, is that the wrong way of editing the column span?

Comment: Your question is off-topic as you fail to properly include the code to reproduce the issue in your question.  Posting a link to your site for others to debug is not what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: Your instagram icon is an `input` wrapped in an `a` so that selector is definitely wrong

Comment: @Axel which code are you missing for it to be on-topic? I don't want other people to debug my site, I want to learn.

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn but changing the instagram icon specifically wouldn't change the column span?

Comment: @ArthurMamou-Mani - Please read the Help guidelines before posting questions if you're not familiar with what is on topic. `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.`

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. I don't know what framework your grid system is based on but i would guess that you want to change the class on the parent element from `span-7` to `span-8`. This will make it one column wider. You don't need to add anything to your css file

Answer (score 0):

The footer.php file contained the following line that overrode the line of CSS:

```
<div class="column span-7.1 append-0.5">
```